# delete fulfilling condition row from a file

Tags: python, perl, shell

I have a file

```
chrM 1114 A A 555 G 52 9.8 xyz
chrM 1256 A A 555 G 0  inf xac
chrM 1184 A A 400 G 50 8 cxv
chrM 1148 p q 500 G 100 5 asad
chrM 2500 x x 555 v 0  inf dad
```

here the 2nd last column is the ratio of  $5/$6 
I want to do delete those line where
 $3=$4  and $8=inf if this whole condition satisfies then it should delete that line
expected output

```
chrM 1114 A A 555 G 52 9.8 xyz
chrM 1184 A A 400 G 50 8 cxv
chrM 1148 p q 500 G 100 5 asad
```

i tried to do

```
while $3=$4
do if %8=inf
do -d 
done
done
```

Comment: Is Python relevant here ?

Comment: rahul sir if its giving me desired output then it is

Answer (score 1):

Use awk simply like:

```
awk '{if ($3 != $4 && $8 != "Inf") { print $0 } }' myfile.txt
```

Comment: but its replacing the 3rd column by 1

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, the solution is pretty much a transcription of your question

```
perl -ane 'print unless $F[2] eq $F[3] and $F[7] eq "inf"' data.txt
```

#### output

```
chrM 1114 A A 555 G 52 9.8 xyz
chrM 1184 A A 400 G 50 8 cxv
chrM 1148 p q 500 G 100 5 asad
```

Could you not even have made an attempt at that? The [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/) is very good, and is also installed as part of the Perl distribution and available through the `perldoc` command on your computer

Answer (score 0):

A python solution to this would be:

```
file = open("myfile.txt")
file2 = open("myfile2.txt", "a")
for i, line in enumerate(file)
    strList = line.split()
    if not (strList[2] == strList[3] and strList[7] == "inf"):
        file2.write(line)
file.close()
file2.close()
```

this assumes that the values are separated by spaces

Comment: if values are \t seperated

Comment: It should work with all white space, but if it doesn't, then you can put "\t" as an argument to line.split() so that it splits by only \t

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '!$3==$4||$8!~/inf/' file
chrM 1114 A A 555 G 52 9.8 xyz
chrM 1184 A A 400 G 50 8 cxv
chrM 1148 p q 500 G 100 5 asad
```

Made a mistake hopefully corrected now.